# « Viewer discretion advised » en français

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction

Je vois souvent sur des sites aux contenus sensibles la mention « Viewer discretion advised ».

Comment pourrait-on traduire cela en français ?

Comment: La première étape consiste à expliquer ce que ça signifie en anglais: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2764/what-does-viewer-discretion-is-advised-mean

Comment: @jlliagre après lecture du lien sur ell, le contexte est plus clair (contenu pour adulte), mais la signification précise de cette *discretion* n'est toujours pas claire.

Comment: @XouDo Il s'agit d'un sens que le mot *discretion* a aussi en français, mais qui est très désuet. On emploierait plutôt aujourd'hui *discernement, sagesse*. Il ne s'agit pas forcément de contenu explictement pour adulte, pour lesquels des classifications plus précises existent, mais plutôt d'un contenu qui doit conduire la personne qui décide du visionnage à réfléchir à la pertinence de ce choix en fonction d'autres critères qui sont aussi documentés.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En France, on trouve la phrase suivante:

Ce service est interdit aux mineurs de moins de 18 ans et est **strictement réservé à un public adulte averti** [etc.] On le voit avec le mot strictement et sans le mot strictement. Cela revient au même.

If you use your discretion, you are a member of a "public averti".

[public  averti_France](https://www.mycanal.fr/nouveautes/h/csatad_them_adulte_nouveautes)

Dans le lien ci-dessus sur un site porno:

> Ce service est interdit aux mineurs de moins de 18 ans et est
> strictement réservé à un public adulte averti

[etc.]

Traduction:

> This service is prohibited for minors under 18 years of age and viewer
> discretion is advised.

Same idea.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse

Comment: En ce moment, j'ai 6 votes négatifs. Avant ils étaient tous positifs.

Comment: Le fait que la traduction que tu proposes soit inexacte (il n'est nullement question en anglais de moins de 18 ans ou d'adultes), ainsi que l'affirmation que *strictement* ne change rien explique probablement ces votes négatifs.

Comment: *One person, one vote...* La partie en gras, qui est donc la traduction proposée d'après ton commentaire, inclus *strictement* (qui n'aurait pas de valeur ici) et *adulte* alors que ces deux notions sont absentes de l'expression anglaise.

Comment: Lá óu on met en France: pour un public averti, on mettrait aux Etats-Unis: viewer discretion advised. Ce sont des formules toutes faites et se correspondent parfaitement.

Answer (score 6):

Lorsque le contenu n'entre pas dans l'une des [catégories du CSA](http://www.csa.fr/Television/Le-suivi-des-programmes/Jeunesse-et-protection-des-mineurs/La-signaletique-jeunesse/Quel-signal-pour-quel-contenu) (ou équivalents dans d'autres pays), on trouve généralement une notice de cette forme:

> Attention, [certaines images] peuvent heurter la sensibilité [des plus jeunes ainsi que des personnes non averties].

On trouve [beaucoup de variations](https://www.google.com/search?q="peuvent+heurter+la+sensibilit%C3%A9").

Avec des contraintes d'espace, « Peut heurter la sensibilité du public » est l'un des choix possibles de traduction.

Answer (score 2):

Au Canada, l'équivalent serait

"[Le visionnement du contenu] est à la discrétion du téléspectateur"

Comment: Voir aussi [_pour public averti_](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8878366). Merci !

Comment: Ce qui est un peu étrange, car chez soi, le visionnage est *toujours* à la discrétion du téléspectateur. Est-ce que ça ne porterait pas la notion de discrétion vis-à-vis des enfant et autre personnes du foyer qui, justement, ne devrait pas voir ce programme. Il s'agirait bien là, de regarder *discrètement*!